# How to stop .ToString("G29") from converting a value less than 0.0001 to a scientific value

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to stop `.ToString("G29")` from converting a value less than `0.0001` to a scientific value. It converts `0.00009` to `9E-05`. But it should give result `0.00009`. I used `.ToString("G29")` to eliminate zeros after a decimal point but it should not remove zeros prior to decimal point.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The "G" format is defined as returning `the most compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation`, so that's not something you can fix.

Comment: "9E-05" is more compact than "0.00009" (5 characters instead of 6) so it sounds like it's behaving as documented, in terms of "The general ("G") format specifier converts a number to the most compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation, depending on the type of the number and whether a precision specifier is present." Do you *ever* want scientific notation to be used? If so, when?

Comment: No I do not want to use scientific notations. Just want to have five decimal values with out showing Unuseful zeros at end of the decimal point. But the zeros before the decimal point should not be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a format specifier of `"0.#############################"`

This forces a value, even if zero, before the decimal point, but then only shows needed values after the point.

Example:

```
double d;
d = 0.0000009;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.#############################"));
d = 9999.00000009;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.#############################"));
```

returns

```
0.0000009
9999.00000009
```

Comment: You won't be able to get 29 significant digits from a double. You'll need to use decimal instead for that level of precision.

Comment: Agree, but the principle of the # placeholder works equally well for decimal as double.